# View multiple emails at the same time with mu4e

Tags: mu4e

I use [`mu4e`](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e.html) to read my emails. I often find myself wanting to see the content of two or three emails at the same time, in different windows in the same frame. However, `mu4e` doesn't seem to allow for this.

Specifically, what I'd like to do is:

- from the Headers view, open a message. This will split the frame into two frames, the headers and the individual message view.
- Then, I'd like to see a second email beside the first. I try moving point to the message view, splitting the window vertically, and then selecting the second message from the headers window
- I'd like for one of the two windows showing the first email body to be replaced by the body of the second email
- what happens instead is that the two message windows are both closed, and replaced by a single window showing the body of the second window.

The exact details aren't crucial here. What I need is a way to simultaneously display the body of two emails at the same time, in different windows in a single Emacs frame. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display one email first and then run `M-x clone-buffer` to get an independent copy of the buffer.  Then select the second email and display it.

Comment: That was a good idea, but it doesn't work. After cloning the buffer, I have two copies. That I can close one of them and move back to the headers view. But as soon as I pick a second message, the 'cloned' buffer is deleted and I see only the second message.

Comment: The cloned buffer is still there.  Switch to `*mu4e-view*<2>` to bring it back up.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to have mu4e relax a bit when creating and hiding new buffers. But this does let me see to messages at once, so one problem solved!